# Objective-C in-between space when retrieving a property

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm returning to Objective-C after a couple of years and I feel perplexed to find that this code compiles:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSView* view = self.view. superview;
}
```

Note the space between `self.view` and `superview`. Other alternatives also work for example:

`NSView* view = self.view .superview`

or a more esoteric one:

`NSView * superView = self   .   view     .   superview;`

Apparently spaces before/after the dot are ignored.

Why is not the compiler throwing an error?

Comment: Why would the compiler throw an error? It knows what you mean. It always bothered me that Swift doesn't allow a space there.

Comment: C ism.  C really doesn't care one whit about whitespace or newlines by and large.  You can put spaces and newlines pretty much anywhere as long as it doesn't change the spelling of something (i.e. don't break up "superview" into "super view").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is standard C. Whitespace is ignored when possible.

One possible use is to make long keypaths more readable, i.e.:

```
NSString *firstName = 
employee.
person.
name.
firstName;
```

The real-world usefulness of this particular syntax feature is debatable, but C (and especially Objective-C) have always embraced espressiveness/flexibility over strictness.

Comment: Almost;   when designing `@property` and the dot syntax, I don't believe we ever even discussed it.   This is more or less just a standard C-ism.  You can add spaces basically anywhere (that doesn't change a symbol name, obviously) and it'll compile fine.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification- edited answer accordingly.